# AES Encryption error: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

Tags: java, encryption, aes, javax.crypto, badpaddingexception

I'm getting the following error with this code: **javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded**. I pointed out where the error is occurring in the program.

```
package aes;

import javax.crypto.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;


public class AESencrpytion {

  //private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[]{'S','e','c','r','e','t'};


  public static String encrypt(String data) throws Exception{
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    keyGen.init(rand);
    Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encValue = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
    return encryptedValue;
  }

  public static String decrypt(String encData) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    keyGen.init(rand);
    Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decodedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encData);
    //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(decodedValue);
    String decryptedVal = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedVal;
  }
```

The main class:

```
package aes;

public class AEStest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String password = "mypassword";
    String passwordEnc = AESencrpytion.encrypt(password);
    String passwordDec = AESencrpytion.decrypt(passwordEnc);

    System.out.println("Plain Text : " + password);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + passwordEnc);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
  }
}
```

I'm new to AES and encryption and this is for a homework assignment. Thank you for the help! I appreciate it.

Comment: If the password is for user authentication, then use PBKDF2 to hash it and compare when the user actually logs in. If this is for something else, use a random IV.

Comment: It is always best to use a fully qualified Cipher like `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use different keys during encryption and decryption, because they are randomly generated in both methods. You have to use the **same** key.

Either add an `init` method to your class to generate the key once or generate the key outside of the class and pass it into both methods.